# Best practise for access mmap'd struct from multiple threads

Tags: rust, atomic, mmap

I have a struct Foo:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct Foo {
    bar: u32,
    baz: u32,
    quux: [u64; 127]
}
```

This question is in the context of implementing a multi-threaded FUSE filesystem, with mmap'd storage in a sparse file.

I would like to turn a pointer to a mmap'd region into an `&mut Foo`.

Multiple threads and/or processes will be setting and reading Foo fields atomically.

(Obviously unsafe blocks/functions are required here.)

How should I approach this?

- Do I need volatile_ptr?
- Should I change the field types to AtomicU32, etc.

I want to make sure that code which uses these mmap-backed `Foo` fields does not get optimised away, or reads and writes reordered.  In C I would `_Atomic` for this, or `volatile` in years past.

Comment: You cannot have multiple `&mut` references to the same thing at the same time, period. If you have multiple writers, you'll need to use atomics or unsafecell.

Comment: Note that you can have multiple `*mut T` which point at the same memory. And you can dereference it, as long as nobody else is reading or writing to that memory.